# ubuntu 20.04 is not installed for LG gram 16, 16Z90P-GA76K

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, lg

First, I installed the window 10, and ubuntu 22.04. And I try to install the ubuntu 20.04 as third native os.

1. I download ISO file(Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS desktop) and make the usb booting disk (I try to UEFI and Legacy/BIOS method, all) using lufus program in window 10.
2. In the boot menu in phoenix bios, I raise the usb drive to the top. And reboot.
3. The computer boots the usb booting disk. The black install screen is output.
4. I select "install ubuntu" and enter it.
5. The screen is black out, the labtop fan noise grows a little and shutdowns. And, the computer is rebooted.

I don't know if it's a crash, a simple error, or overheating.

ps. iso and hardware

iso file name : "ubuntu-20.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso".

notebook name : "16Z90P-GA76K."

CPU : i7-1165G7 (2.8GHz)

Memory : LPDDR4x 4266 MHz 16 GB

Network : Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX201 (Wi-Fi 6, 2x2, BT Combo)

Comment: You've not ruled out user-procedure type errors too.  You've not told us what Ubuntu 20.04 LTS product you're asking about (desktop? server? which ISO thus which kernel stack was included by default on the ISO), nor what checks you performed (ISO validation? write of ISO to media?) for your *unstated* 20.04 ISO.  I'm also unsure what your "*install usb in bios*" means but I don't know your hardware; but your chosen words highlight that as a possible issue too (*but maybe okay; just words I'd not use*).  Depending on what 20.04 ISO you used; I'd return to verify steps.

Comment: I add the hardware spec and iso file information.